# Simplifying class structure of compiler

Tags: class, structure, antlr, divide

So i'm writing a compiler in java that translates my own language to the CUDA language. For this task i have written a grammar in ANTLR4, getting a lexer and parser.

Now, ANTLR gives me a Listener with implementable methods which basically are nodes in the abstract parse tree. I then decorate this tree with the code i want to generate, based on the tokens on this node.

My problem is that i have 45 methods in this CUDAEmitter class, and 830 lines of code. I am struggling to figure out how to structure and divide these methods. I use these 3 to decorate my nodes:

```
private final ParseTreeProperty<String> cuda = new ParseTreeProperty<String>();
String getCode(ParseTree ctx) { return cuda.get(ctx); }
void setCode(ParseTree ctx, String s) { cuda.put(ctx, s); }
```

example of code generation:

```
public void exitIdvalString(ParmaParser.IdvalStringContext ctx) {
 String str = ctx.STRING().getText();
 setCode(ctx, str);     
}
```

How do i go about splitting up this class? Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Doubtful that this is a best solution, but [GenPackage](https://github.com/GRosenberg/GenPackage) represents one approach.  It does automated generation of node and supporting classes.  The generator can be re-run at any time to fill in missing classes.  I have not seen any other generally implemented solution.

Full disclosure: I am the author of GenPackage.  If the basic approach is of interest, I have an outstanding commit that adds symbol table support and a few additional features.

Comment: How do i generate in linux? There seems to be no run.bat file